# Can't Find variable in Phonegap using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

when i run this program on browser i am getting response as fail, but run this in android phone i am getting reference error can't find variable **data**. Code perfectly works in emulator also. Help Me

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function getResponse(){

    var url = "http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/phone_gap/uname_validation.asp?un=9999999999&pwd=123456789&callback=your_callback";

    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script= document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';
        script.src= url;
        head.appendChild(script);

     your_callback(data);    //here i am getting reference error, can't find  variable data

     }

    function  your_callback(data){

    var st = data.status;
    alert(st);

    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button input type = "button" onClick = "getResponse()"> GetResponse </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can't find the variable `data` either =\ Where is it supposed to be defined?

Comment: when calling `your_callback`, `data` is not defined to anything, so that should not be surprising. What do you want `your_callback` to work with?

Comment: Antoher thing: Best practice is to define functions before using them - so I would recoment moving the definition of `your_callback` abpve the definition of `getResponse`.

Comment: i am not declare data variable, where i have to declare

Comment: check my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhatEver I understood from your code I have added some code in it, please check my answer below:

I have also added data variable declaration and get value from it.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

   var data=""; // Declare varible here so that you can get variable in both function.
        function getResponse(){

        var url = "http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/phone_gap/uname_validation.asp?un=9999999999&pwd=123456789&callback=your_callback";

        var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script= document.createElement('script');
            script.type= 'text/javascript';
            script.src= url;
            data = head.appendChild(script); // get your script value in data variable

         your_callback(data);    //here i am getting reference error, can't find  variable data

         }

        function  your_callback(data){

        var st = data.value;
        alert('script value is: '+st);

        }


        </script>
```

Make sure that you have put html file in assest/www folder & this code:

By using web view you can use java script and html page.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
//        webView.loadUrl("WebAppDemo/assets/www/index.html");



    }

}
```

Comment: i try this code, first time i am getting alert as undefined. It's working in browser and emulator, but y it's nt working in android mobile.

Comment: Try using alert('script value is: ' +data.value); actually I don't know about status thing but If you want to get value from variable then you can get by using .value (Like: + document.getElementById('username').value).

Comment: check this link for alert dialog example in phone gap it will help you: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/ and also check my edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

The value of your url variable should be used with a JSONP [1] call. There are stand alone helper libraries [2] or the Jquery option [3]. You should use one of them, as you don't have to do manually with all JSONP mechanics.

I noticed also that you include both phonegap.js and cordova.js. You should remove the first. It is really old.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

[2] http://pastebin.com/ADxHdCnB

[3] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/