# How to run javascript app by creating android project?

Tags: javascript, android

Hi I have app which is written in javascript. Now i want to create a android project by using this javascript code.

Can any one please guide me how can i do this. I mean how to call javascript userintereface, javascript functions in my android code.

If possible please provide me a good tutorial guide where i can read in detail and understand the actual things. I have searched it on google but didnt find any thing so posting here.

Any help is appricated.
Than

Comment: gothrough the 'Phonegap' concept in android

Comment: No. using phonegap i can just call urls. I want to modify some of the functionalities also

Answer (score 0):

check this link:
[Can't Find variable in Phonegap using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889519/cant-find-variable-in-phonegap-using-javascript/14890192#14890192)

and also I have prefer this link for more details for initial developer.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/

I have explained how to use phone gap and java script in android project in first link.

Hope it will help you.